# Design UIView subclass auto layout with custom size in Interface Builder xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I have an UIView subclass with its layout in a `.xib` file. I set the size to freeform and the dimensions to something like 200 x 300.

How can I set different dimensions for iPad so the "View as" option correctly show a preview of how it would look like?

Or, can this be achieved in a different way? Maybe using a storyboard instead of a xib file?

Comment: You want to work with IB_Designable to see the view during design time. Pulling it out of a XIB is actually much easier with Swift than Objective-C (or, at least, it seems so). See the example in my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Similar kind of feature I did last week. I had an xib file and that I was using as a collectionView item. Through interface builder it cannot be differed. I achieved this programmatically. You can change the size of UIView as required.

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: I know and did this, as it correctly works on all devices. But the downside is that I can't preview the layout and I have to run the app in the simulator on different devices.

Comment: Yes you cannot preview it even though you can change the size of UIView in interface builder to get a glance how it looks like.

Comment: I understand. I'll keep this open for more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, you can make it compatible with Auto Layout and you can use IBDesignable to do visual layout in Interface Builder.

I have a couple examples - including loading custom views from XIB files - here: https://github.com/DonMag/IBDesignInspect