# Best way to update constraint outlet constant programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I have a width constraint in a `.xib` file which I connected to an outlet, and I want to change its `constant` for iPhone 6.

Between this one:

```
//
//  MyViewController.m
//

#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraintViewWidth;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isConstraintsUpdated;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)updateViewConstraints {

    if (!self.isConstraintsUpdated) {
        if (CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) == 667) {
            constraintViewWidth.constant = 60;
        }

        self.isConstraintsUpdated = YES;
    }

    [super updateViewConstraints];
}

@end
```

and this one:

```
//
//  MyViewController.m
//

#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraintViewWidth;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isLayoutLoaded;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if (!self.isLayoutLoaded) {
        if (CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) == 667) {
            constraintViewWidth.constant = 60;
        }

        self.isLayoutLoaded = YES;
    }
}

@end
```

which is the preferred one?

I tried using the first, but it doesn't work, as the custom constant gets overridden by the one in the `.xib` file, though it would make the most sense to change it in `updateViewConstraints`.

The second one works but I don't see why would I want to change a constraint when the layout finishes.

Comment: Seems like an odd task... You have a UIView - presumably with subviews - in a .xib, and you have constraints on those elements in the .xib... but then you need to modify a constraint to a constant when the view is loaded? Why not just set the value in the .xib to begin with?

Comment: @DonMag, Sorry, forgot something. I updated my question.

Comment: You could just set the width to be *proportional* to the whole view's width

Comment: @Rikh, I can't do that, as I actually need that for an icon image view.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei - still seems like an odd approach, but... I just tried that in a custom view in a .xib file and it works fine putting the code in my .xib setup method.

Comment: @DonMag, What would be the best approach? And, what is "xib setup method"?

Comment: By proportional i mean you can add a multiplier like 0.09 that will ensure the image is quite small depending on different screen resolutions. Soo like if whole view width is 500, 0.09 * 500 = 45 points.

Comment: @Rikh, And what happens if the iPad version of the icon has a different aspect ratio?

Comment: Same concept, 0.09 * 1000 = 90. Whatever width is of the device, just multiply by 0.09

Comment: But I can't set a different multiplier in the `.xib` file based on size classes.

Comment: I meant, in your example, if I want the iPad image to be 120 and not 90.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei - see my answer (I also posted that as an answer to one of your previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860812/design-uiview-subclass-auto-layout-with-custom-size-in-interface-builder-xib-fil

Comment: You will have to appropriately set the multiplier...i just gave an example...

Comment: You can't set different multipliers for different size classes, nor change it at runtime. You can only remove the constraint and add a new one.